# Using the MAX() clause in Access 2007 SQL View

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am newer to Access and VBA, I'm coding in Access 2007 and attempting to build a query that will pull records from two different tables, the records in the tables have revision numbers assigned each time a revision is made. I can get the query to run and display the records, however I'm trying to pull "only" the most current revision of each record. I have tried using the MAX() clause written in SQL view for both the max revision number (I.E. rev1 rev2 rev3) as well as the most current date of the revisions (to pull the most recent date for the revisions). In both attempts Access is displaying all revisions for the records pulled. Am I not able to pull only the most current revision in Access? Below is the SQL code I've attempted to use,

```
SELECT MAX(tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum) AS tbRevisionNum, tblNasco.tbNCRNumber, tblNasco.tbGroupName, tblNasco.tbGroupNumber, tblNasco.tbAccountManager, tblNasco.tbSERNumber, tblNasco.cboNCRAnalyst, tblNasco.tbBAReceivedDate, tblNasco.tbBAAcceptedDate, tblNasco.tbRequestTitle, tblNasco.tbSubmittedToMDSS, tblNasco.tbImplementationDate,  tblNasco.tbRejectToSales1, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales1, tblNasco.tbRejectToSales2, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales2, tblNasco.tbComments, tblNascoRevision.tbSentToMDSS, tblNascoRevision.cboRevisionCodes

FROM tblNasco, tblNascoRevision

WHERE tblNasco.LocalID=tblNascoRevision.NascoLocalID

GROUP BY tblNasco.tbNCRNumber, tblNasco.tbGroupName, tblNasco.tbGroupNumber, tblNasco.tbAccountManager, tblNasco.tbSERNumber, tblNasco.cboNCRAnalyst, tblNasco.tbBAReceivedDate, tblNasco.tbBAAcceptedDate, tblNasco.tbRequestTitle, tblNasco.tbSubmittedToMDSS, tblNasco.tbImplementationDate, tblNasco.tbRejectToSales1, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales1, tblNasco.tbRejectToSales2, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales2, tblNasco.tbComments, tblNascoRevision.tbSentToMDSS, tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum

ORDER BY tblNasco.tbGroupName, tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum DESC;
```

Comment: I'm not a SQL expert but I think you need use the WHERE clause to down select.  Something like `WHERE tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum= (SELECT MAX(tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum) FROM tblNascoRevision)`  I think you need some more conditions in the WHERE clause to get the answer you're looking for but I'm not quite sure what you need.

Comment: @Sobigen is right. See this page under section "Frequently Asked Question" the example is exactly your case:  http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php

Comment: Thank you both very much!!! This is EXACTLY what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve it creating two queries:

Query 1:  get only max recordsets of tblNascoRevision

```
SELECT tbRevisionNum, NascoLocalID, tbSentToMDSS, cboRevisionCodes
FROM tblNascoRevision rev,

 (SELECT MAX(tblNascoRevision.tbRevisionNum) AS tbRevisionNum, NascoLocalID
  FROM tblNascoRevision
  GROUP BY NascoLocalID) maxresults

 WHERE rev.tbRevisionNum = maxresults.tbRevisionNum
 AND rev.NascoLocalID= maxresults.NascoLocalID;
```

Query 2: Join Query1 with tblNasco

```
SELECT Query1.tbRevisionNum, tblNasco.tbNCRNumber, tblNasco.tbGroupName, tblNasco.tbGroupNumber, tblNasco.tbAccountManager, tblNasco.tbSERNumber, tblNasco.cboNCRAnalyst, tblNasco.tbBAReceivedDate, tblNasco.tbBAAcceptedDate, tblNasco.tbRequestTitle, tblNasco.tbSubmittedToMDSS, tblNasco.tbImplementationDate,  tblNasco.tbRejectToSales1, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales1, tblNasco.tbRejectToSales2, tblNasco.tbReceiveFromSales2, tblNasco.tbComments, Query1.tbSentToMDSS, Query1.cboRevisionCodes
FROM tblNasco, Query1
WHERE tblNasco.LocalID=Query1.NascoLocalID
ORDER BY tblNasco.tbGroupName, Query1.tbRevisionNum DESC;
```